# What is the meaning of i=j--

Tags: java, drjava

this is my first question here, and I'm glad to join the community.
I have a test tomorrow, and in one of the examples there is that line

```
i=0; j=2; z=2
i=j--;
```

What is the exact operation that is done? Because I know that j-- means j-1 everytime.
Thanks!
I'm using Dr.Java.

EDIT: It was a duplicate. Should I delete?

Answer (score 6):

`i = j--;` is an assignment statement. The right-hand side is evaluated, and the resulting value is assigned to the thing on the left-hand side. In your case, that means:

1. The value of `j` is read (`2`, in that code)
2. `j` is decremented (to `1`, in that code)
3. The value read in step 1 (`2`) is assigned to `i`

The order of Steps 1 and 2 is because the `--` is *after* the `j`; it's the *postfix decrement operator*. If it were before the `j` (the ***prefix*** decrement operator), steps 1 and 2 would be reversed.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And one supplementary question: with i = 3; j = 2; z= 2, we have z= i++%j; what should i do on that line?

Comment: @Román: If you break it down into its parts (as above), what do *you* think happens?

Comment: I'm not sure, but think it's the same as you said before: First we assign to z the value of i%j (in this case 3%2, so z=1) and then we do in a next line i++ so i+1 (in this case 3+1). Am I right? I'm really thankfull for your help, my first months of programming and loving it!

Answer (score 4):

It means set i equal to j and then subtract one from j.

Answer (score 1):

It is another shortcut for this code.

```
i=0; j=2; z=2
i = j;
j = j - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that i will have as value 2, because you used a post-decrement operator.
J will have the value of 1 since it is decremented.
If you had written:

```
i = --j
```

then i will have the value of 1, since the value is decremented BEFORE assignment.

Gerald